PWA Scandi cart and checkout page is not showing
I have installed the Scandi PWA on the Magento 2.4.6 Community.
Its working fine but it doesn't go to the cart and checkout page it gives me this error in the logs.
previous exception] [object] (Magento\\Framework\\GraphQl\\Exception\\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The CMS page with the \"index.php/cart\" ID doesn't exist. at /directory/directory/www/directory.scandi/vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Page.php:64)
[previous exception] [object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The CMS page with the \"index.php/cart\" ID doesn't exist. at /directory/directory/www/directory.scandi/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/GetPageByIdentifier.php:50)"} []

Suggest me the solution for this
